# Most likely future sample return missions?

Tags: planetary-science, sample-return, planning

Please bear in mind I have very little space/astronomy knowledge with any comments or answers but I am curious and quite keen to learn.

Aside from Mars itself as that is such a likely candidate, what would be the next most likely space planet or one of its moons (no asteroids or comets please) for a rock, soil or other sample to be brought back to Earth?

Leaving a "Rover" on the surface (so we are excluding the gas giants sadly unless planned on a gaseous sample) is fine too but the sample should be sent back.

Excluding the planet Mars, which planet or moon "samples" are most likely be returned next?

Comment: "Aside from Mars itself as that is such a likely candidate, what would be the next most likely space body to look to bring a rock/soil sample back to earth.", that's going to be the Japanese Hayabusa2 in late 2020.

Comment: there seem to be two questions here:  which are we most likely to be able to and choose to;  and which would be "beneficial".  The latter is highly opinion-based.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft , Was meant/intended to be a single question in that not the type of sample=important only the place/body to obtain it from. By beneficial it should be perhaps read as a "body we know little about but is high up on list of objects of value interest" and worth the time expenditure to do this (financial costs should not play too high into any answer for this as it's hypothetical question) I know what you're saying though :) Buy I could not think of a better way to structure the initial question. English language not best, usually adequate though I hope. Edits are perfectly fine.

Comment: Can't you say the sample would be most beneficial only after you have examined and learned from it ?  Because the gas giants are excluded my opinion would be that a sample from Venus would be most beneficial because it has a hot surface and atmosphere which interact with each other.

Comment: I've adjusted your question so that answers can be fact-based. In Stack Exchange we should't ask "What do you think?" or similar questions where the answers can be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for taking the time to do that. I appreciate the edit to better compose the question.

Comment: For what is it probably not worth the primary reason I initially said to exclude Mars (the planet itself only , not excluding any of its moons) was simply as it appeared (to an unqualified mind such as myself) to be by far the most likely suggestion given we have a fair bit of activity there. That and the fact we already have samples from our own main moon, pleased I did not have to mention excluding that one as common sense prevailed.

Comment: @AndyF "our own main moon"  -- there are more, smaller moons orbiting Earth?

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi , I was at the time of writing that thinking of the tiny other body called "Cruithne" although I forgot to check its erm status before posting my comment. It would seem said body does not qualify as "another moon" I think. Oops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One mission planned for launch inv2024 is the Japanese [**M**artian **M**oons E**X**ploration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_Moons_Exploration).  MMX will land on Phobos to collect and return samples, as well as flying by Deimos and studying the Martian climate.

Comment: What is Maxwell?

Comment: Maxwell is my device getting away from me, which I attempted to correct.  If I were ever to go to Mars I would mistype it with my fat, uncoordinated fingers and the entire social media world would see me going to Mercury.

Comment: Yes Phobos is fine, as although I purposely excluded Mars I was deliberately careful to not attempt to exclude any of its moons/orbiting bodies.